# ToolTipservice.ShowOnDisabled Not Working in Template Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

I am new to WPF and struggling to get tooltips working on disabled controls.

I have a list of Commands built "behind the scenes" in code. These commands are associated with radio buttons, rendered as toggle buttons using a resource template that defines the styles. The functionality works fine, as does the display, save for one piece:

I need to display to the user, only when the button is disabled, a tool tip.

I cannot seem to get the tooltips to display on disabled buttons. I have tried setting ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled "true" everywhere I can think to try, and made sure IsHitTestVisible is "true", but nothing seems to work. Of course, a simple test using a disabled button on a window works fine - I am assuming something in the complexity of the rendering is causing my "show on disabled" not to be associated with the right part of the tree.

I have simplified things to remove the triggers related to enabling and disabling the tool tips based on the enable state of the buttons. At this point, I believe if I can get the tool tips showing on the disabled buttons, I will be able to implement the rest.  But I sure do need help getting the tool tips to display when the buttons are disabled.

This is the relevant part of my Resource XAML.

This snip defines the radio buttons themselves and their binding :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CommandsTemplate" >
    <ItemsControl IsTabStop="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="0,2" >
                <RadioButton
                    GroupName="CommandList"
                    Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"
                    Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Command.CanExecute}"
                    Style="{StaticResource CommandButtonStyle}"

                >
                </RadioButton >
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

This snip defines the command buttons layout itself. Obviously the tool tip here is setup to display on enabled buttons as well as disabled, but if I can get them displaying on the disabled ones, I'll be able to take it from there :

```
<Style x:Key="CommandButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" >
                <Border
                        x:Name="border"
                        Padding="0,0,0,0"
                        CornerRadius="1,1,1,1"
                        Background="#cfd2d6"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        MinWidth="170"
                        MinHeight="35"
                        IsHitTestVisible="True"
                        ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
                        ToolTip="This is a tool tip I want to see."
                    >
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        />


                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#003f73"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#ecf0f3"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I really appreciate the help - I use stack overflow constantly and have learned so much, but never before have I just hit a complete dead end. I don't know what else to try. So, I thought I would ask. Thank you --

EDIT:  I have uploaded code showing the problem to GitHub. You can see the remains of Dev Hedgehogs code in it; I started with his working example and added to it until the problem reoccurred. The issue started when I added the inner ItemsControl back in to accommodate the more elaborate view model.

The code is in a zip file -- ToolTipTester.Zip. I hope that is ok. The Zip contains the full project.

https://github.com/Bearjing/TooltipTestApp/tree/657eb910df6654e61a3228958bc5e854c808e70e

Comment: It works for me :) Let me post you an example. Maybe it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you very much dev hedgehog, I will try your code and see if I can get it working, then maybe that will highlight the difference. I'll get the view model to you also but will need to strip it down a bit for simplicity. I will let you know what I find, and thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

It works all fine for me though I had to change your DataTemplate a little bit to fit my ViewModel. I didn't know how your ViewModel looked alike so I needed to create my own.

This is the ViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> employee;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.Employee = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        this.Employee.Add(new Person { Name = "Test" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Employee
    {
        get { return this.employee; }
        set { this.employee = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Employee"); }
    }

    ...
```

This is XAML part:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CommandButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" >
                    <Border
                        x:Name="border"
                        Padding="0,0,0,0"
                        CornerRadius="1,1,1,1"
                        Background="#cfd2d6"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        MinWidth="170"
                        MinHeight="35"
                        IsHitTestVisible="True"
                        ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
                        ToolTip="This is a tool tip I want to see.">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#003f73"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#ecf0f3"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CommandsTemplate">
        <RadioButton
            GroupName="CommandList"
            IsChecked="True"
            Content="test"
            IsEnabled="false"
            Style="{StaticResource CommandButtonStyle}">
        </RadioButton>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CommandsTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

I had to throw the inner ItemsControl away since my ViewModel doesn't support tree alike data structure. The person class has no futher lists inside.

However it works all fine.

Take a look at the picture.

[image]

Could you please provide us with full code so we have also the same ViewModel as you.

Futhermore remember for any futher questions always give the complete code to us.

Upload it on github.com or anywhere else.

Comment: I was able to use your code (thank you again) to make a working version, but when I added the ItemsControl back in, the problem reoccurred.  I have uploaded the code to git hub - you will see the remains of your version above in it, but in it's current state the tool tip does not display on the disabled button. The code is in a zip file -- ToolTipTester.Zip. I hope that is ok.  The Zip contains the full project. https://github.com/Bearjing/TooltipTestApp/tree/657eb910df6654e61a3228958bc5e854c808e70e